# how to update all document of particular mongoDB collection

Tags: java, mongodb

Below is my code

```
       int min=10;
         int max=150;
         String Col_name="indexValueO";
         System.out.println("B4 Time: "+new Date());
         BasicDBObject searchQuery =new BasicDBObject(Col_name, new BasicDBObject("$gte", min).append("$lte", max));
         BasicDBObject updateFields = new BasicDBObject();
         updateFields.append("color", "rgba(128,18,18,0.6)");
         BasicDBObject setQuery = new BasicDBObject();
         setQuery.append("$set", updateFields);
         coll.update(searchQuery, setQuery);
        LOGGER.info("Updated ");
        System.out.println("After Time: "+new Date());
```

Here only one document is updated even many fields matches the condition

Comment: use coll.updateMulti(searchQuery, setQuery); cf http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overloaded update method which takes the 4th argument as multi to allow updating multiple documents.

> public WriteResult update(DBObject q,
>                    DBObject o,
>                    boolean upsert,
>                    boolean multi)

Pass multi as true.

Or

Use overloaded method which implicitly sets multi to true.

> public WriteResult updateMulti(DBObject q,
>                         DBObject o)